# NSTableView weird issue

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have implemented viewbased NSTableView. When i scroll downwards, lines are drawn at the bottom of the NSTableView. Even the text of the buttons which are not the part of NSTableView get darker. I removed the NSTableView Datasource method and buttons' texts are fine, but still lines are drawn at the bottom of the NSTableView.

I do not know weather these two things are connected. I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Check if your table view and the bottom view are overlapping by 1 px.

Comment: Problem is solved. Thanks. Do you have any idea why text of the button gets bold ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is general problem of NSScrollView, inside which lies your table view.

If table view's enclosing scroll view `drawsBackground` property is `NO`, uncheck Copy On Scroll too.

If the scroll view is overlapped by other views, either enable Core Animation layer on that views or eliminate overlapping.

Comment: I removed the overlapping and now its fine. But text of the button still is bold. When i remove the datasource method of NSTableView its fine. Do these things have any relation? Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Does that button overlap with scroll view too? Try moving it up or enabling CA layer for it.

Comment: NSTableView's Datasource method viewForTableColumn was calling -awakeFromNib for every row. In -awakeFromNib I was adding NSButton. Thats why NSButton text gets bold.